# Pulling a list from a file and abbreviating names

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a program that will pull a list from a file and list the names. It will also tell me how many names there are. I am stuck on how i can abbreviate the names to add along with the names from the list. For example, the name John A Doe is pulled from a file that has a list of names from a job. I want it to also list the initials as an abbreviation. For this instance i want it to say "JAD" as the acronym next to the name. Here is the code i have so far:

```
def main():
      outfile = open("workersList.txt", 'r')

      workers = 0.0

      for line in outfile:
           workers = workers + 1
           print(line.rstrip("\n))

      print()
      print("Total number of workers is:",workers)

      outfile.close()

main()
```

I am stuck on hoe to also include the acronym (First, Middle, Last) next to the name. My list includes 14 names total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each line is a persons name in the form of `John A Doe` you can do

```
initials = "".join([namepart[0].upper() for namepart in line.split()])
```

This will split the name on each space, and then take the first character of each 'part'.
The `.upper()` just converts it to uppercase, if that's what you want.

Then you can just print `initials` next to the name, or whatever you like

```
print(initials + " " + line.rstrip("\n"))
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or above take a look at using [f-string's](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for printing - they make print formatting much easier than concatenating strings, as above.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, be sure to accept the answer so others can find it in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

We can split the name string into an array, then apply a map to grab the first character from each element of the array, finally use reduce to concatenate the abbreviated letters.

```py
import functools

def abbreviate_name(name):
    return str(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda x: x[0], name.split())))
```

Using this function with your code we get...

```py
import functools

def abbreviate_name(name):
    return str(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda x: x[0], name.split())))

def main():
      outfile = open("workersList.txt", 'r')

      workers = 0.0

      for line in outfile:
           workers = workers + 1
           print(abbreviate_name(line.rstrip("\n")))

      print()
      print("Total number of workers is:",workers)

      outfile.close()

main()
```